# Example of a group with at least 3 generators?

Tags: group-theory

The answer to this question could be trivial, but usually I do not work in group theory.

> Is there a nonabelian  group $G$ that is generated by $S$ where $3\leq
>  |S|\leq |G|-1$?

I notice most of the nonabelian groups like dihedral, symmetric group,.. does not satisfy this condition.

Any help will be useful!

Comment: Just take a direct product of some non-abelian groups.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft Does the direct  product of the  generating set gives the generating set of the new group?

Comment: The union of the generating sets will be a generating set (though it is not quite clear that it needs to be minimal even if the individual ones are chosen minimal)

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft Thanks for the help!

Comment: For a direct product of $p$-groups (for a fixed prime $p$), the minmal number of generators is the sum of the minimal generator numbers of the direct factors. So for example the direct product of a dihedral group of order $8$ with a cyclic  group of order $2$ is a $3$-generator group.

Comment: The minimal examples have order $16$, and there are three of them: The direct products $D_8 \times Z_2$ and $Q_8 \times Z_2$, and the central product of $D_8$ and $Z_4$ (http://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Central_product_of_D8_and_Z4).

Comment: @DerekHolt@Travis Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because of its definition the [free group of n-generators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_group) (with $n \ge 3$) satisfies the property you're interested in (this is an infinite group, I don't know if you're just interested in finite ones).